# Remove something in a match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex. My problem is the two second lines of the code:

```
<% 
content = ""+Request.Form("completehtml")+"";
contentmatch = content;
contentmatch = content.match(/<div class="content">[\s\S]+?#-#/ig); 
htstring1 = contentmatch;
htstring2 = htstring1.replace(/#-#/ig, '');
 %>
```

I want to match something and then after everything is matched, remove the `#-#` within the match

Is this possible?

I have found this to work:

```
contentmatch.match(/(<div class="content">[\s\S]+?)(?=[##])/ig);
```

But I still want to know how to use match and then replace within the math?

Anybody ?

Comment: which lines are you having a problem with?

Comment: htstring1 = contentmatch; 
htstring2 = htstring1.replace(/#-#/ig, '');

Comment: `[##]` is the same as `[#]` which is the same a `#`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its possible, and doable, but you should be able to do it in one step with groupings:

```
/(<div class="content">[\s\S]+?)#-#/ig
```

and then grab the group (enclosed via the parenthases), which will skip your need for the second regex.

(Every language allows you to reference groupings in a different way, and you dont' specify a language, so i didn't provide an explicit example of referencing the group.)

Comment: I am using Javascript - Thanks for the comment will look into groupings

Comment: contentmatch.match(/(<div class="content">[\s\S]+?)(?=[##])/ig);